# How to dispose of in-flight requests

Tags: rxjs

**Right now the script works like this:**

I press the button and get a value after 3 seconds.
 If I press the button twice I get two values with a delay between them equal to the time between clicks.
 My question is how do I ignore the previous requests when I click the button again. In other words, each new click must garantee
 that I get the next value in 3 seconds and nothing in between.

---

```
//foo.js I CAN CHANGE EVERYTHING HERE

import * as bar from './bar';
let oldValue;

bar.subject.subscribe(newValue => {
  oldValue = newValue
});

Rx.fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(() => {
  bar.getValue();
});
```

---

```
//bar.js IT MUST NOT CHANGE

const subject = new Subject();

const getValue = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(Math.random());
  }, 3000);
};

exports {subject, getValue};
```

Comment: If the delay is hardcoded in `setTimeout()` then I don't think you can do anything about it because it's out of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you describe happens a lot in web development and is called debouncing.

I will restrict myself to your specific example, but note that rxjs has diverse solutions depending on what getValue really does. If for example it is a backend request, rxjs has a AJAX client [1] usable from the browsers that knows how to actually cancel previous AJAX requests (requests are still run until the end on the server side but any results are not processed by the browser).

For the very specific case shown here, you would need to decide what specifically needs to be ignored. Should clicks prior to the last click within the past 3 seconds be ignored (and getValue only be called once every 3 seconds? In such a case

```
Rx.fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(() => bar.getValue());
```

becomes

```
Rx.fromEvent(document, 'click').debounceTime(3000).subscribe(() => bar.getValue());
```

You may want to do this if **bar.getValue()** is a very resource intensive function that should only be called once.

If you decided to not ignore clicks but just ignore previous results of bar.getValue() generated within 3 seconds, then you would replace

```
bar.subject.subscribe(newValue => oldValue = newValue);
```

with

```
bar.subject.debounceTime(3000).subscribe(newValue => oldValue = newValue);
```

I cannot assess whether you have used a subject because it is what you will really need, yet it is likely you don't need that indirection and you could simply have a single stream. If **getValue** is cancelable (when unsubscribed it stops generating and when resubscribed to it starts generating the value again) you would likely link the click to getting the value using **switchMap** and it would cancel any obsolete **getValue** before it is completed.

[1] https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md